# Proof check: Expectation of squared sum of independent mean zero random vectors

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $Z_1,...,Z_k$ be independent mean zero random vectors in $R^n$. Show that
\begin{equation*}
E\left\| \sum_{j=1}^{k} Z_j \right\|_2^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{k} E \left\| Z_j \right\|_2^2
\end{equation*}
Proof:
Let $X=Z_1+...+Z_k$ and $X^i,Z_j^i$ the ith component of $X,Z_j$.
\begin{equation}
E\left\| \sum_{j=1}^{k} Z_j \right\|_2^2=E [(X^1)^2+...(X^k)^2]=\sum_{i=1}^k E[(\sum_{j=1}^k Z_j^i)^2] 
\end{equation}
Then for a fixed $i$
\begin{equation}
(\sum_{j=1}^k Z_j^i)^2=\sum_{j=1}^k (Z_j^i)^2+R.
\end{equation}
The $R$ will consist of summands $Z_x^i Z_y^i$ with $x\neq y$. Because our random vectors are independent (this means the single components are also independent, right ?) we have $E[R]=0$. After some simple calculations the statement follows. Is this correct ?